# How to filter JSON data to show fields by certain words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm looking for a way to get a URL from JSON data that matches certain words. I'm not familiar with JSON but my JSON data looks like this:

```
const data = {
  "links": {
    "thumbnail": [{
        "href": "https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0_1920x1080.jpg",
        "rel": [
          "thumbnail",
          "ssl"
        ],
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "content_length": 123865,
        "media": {
          "width": 1920,
          "height": 1080
        }
      },
      {
        "href": "https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00_1140x641.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "rel": [
          "twitter",
          "thumbnail",
          "ssl",
          "og"
        ],
        "media": {
          "width": 1140,
          "height": 641
        },
        "content_length": 94781
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And my AJAX function is below. What it does is get JSON data and then store them in a value in a field:

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "https://iframe.ly/api/iframely?url=" + link_raw.value + "&api_key=xxx",
      success: function(data) {
               $(".acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-62a253c405887 div.acf-input div.acf-input-wrap input").val(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.links.thumbnail[0].href)));
       },
       dataType: 'JSON',
});
```

What I'm trying to do is show the `href` if `rel[0].twitter`. Something like:

```
if (filter == rel[0].twitter) {
    $(".acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-62a253c405887 div.acf-input div.acf-input-wrap input").val(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.links.thumbnail)));
}
```

Comment: `data.links.thumbnail = data.links.thumbnail.filter(t => t.rel.includes('twitter')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter each object by whether `twitter` is included in the `rel` array:

```js
const data = {"links":{"thumbnail":[{"href":"https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0_1920x1080.jpg","rel":["thumbnail","ssl"],"type":"image/jpg","content_length":123865,"media":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"href":"https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00_1140x641.jpg","type":"image/jpg","rel":["twitter","thumbnail","ssl","og"],"media":{"width":1140,"height":641},"content_length":94781}],},};

const filterBy = toFilter => {
  return data.links.thumbnail.filter(({ rel }) => rel.includes(toFilter));
};

console.log(filterBy("twitter"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You can also just extract the `href` from those if you'd like only the URL associated with the item:

```js
const data = {"links":{"thumbnail":[{"href":"https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0_1920x1080.jpg","rel":["thumbnail","ssl"],"type":"image/jpg","content_length":123865,"media":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"href":"https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00_1140x641.jpg","type":"image/jpg","rel":["twitter","thumbnail","ssl","og"],"media":{"width":1140,"height":641},"content_length":94781}],},};

const filterBy = toFilter => {
  return data.links.thumbnail.filter(({ rel }) => rel.includes(toFilter)).map(({ href }) => href);
};

console.log(filterBy("twitter"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

To exclude one, just invert the filter clause:

```js
const data = {"links":{"thumbnail":[{"href":"https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0/d111cadc-2ca1-4cfc-adec-422d9228e6a0_1920x1080.jpg","rel":["thumbnail","ssl"],"type":"image/jpg","content_length":123865,"media":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"href":"https://media.wwltv.com/assets/WWL/images/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00/b9c0109f-f504-4330-9dbb-5d0461316d00_1140x641.jpg","type":"image/jpg","rel":["twitter","thumbnail","ssl","og"],"media":{"width":1140,"height":641},"content_length":94781}],},};

const filterBy = (toFilter, toExclude) => {
  return data.links.thumbnail.filter(({ rel }) => toExclude ? !rel.includes(toFilter) : rel.includes(toFilter));
};

console.log(filterBy("twitter", true));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you never much. One question: how do you exclude an entry? For example, if rel has Twitter but does not contain thumbnail. I've tried `((filterBy("twitter")) and !(filterBy("thumbnail"))` and that didn't work.

Comment: I would filter by whether the item is not in the second entry. I'll update my answer in a second @GregorySchultz

Comment: @GregorySchultz answer updated - now you can pass `true` if you want to exclude rather than include, and `false` otherwise. Feel free to invert that logic if you'd like.